# Prevent AJAX POST responses from being cached

Tags: ajax, http

I have AJAX POST requests generated from my webpage, and there may be multiple post requests with the same post data. But the response may vary, and I want to make sure I am not getting cached responses to any of these requests. I need each request to hit the webpage.

Am I right in assuming that responses to POST requests will not be cached?

Answer (score 1):

There is two level of caching will be involved in that process

- Browser caching
- Server caching

To eliminate first one you have to cheat your browser and add a fake parameter to your ajax request so it will think it's unique each time i.e

```
www.example.com/api/ajax?123
www.example.com/api/ajax?1234
```

For server level you have to make sure that no cache been added to your configuration for such link, for example some developer will cache any file ends with .json or service like Cloud Flare it will automatically cache any static content.

Comment: The method to prevent browser caching is to add a proper `Cache-Control` header to the server's response. Adding a random parameter is an unnecessary hack.

Comment: I know this is true for GET requests, and that an easy way to prevent this is to add a timestamp to the querystring or something like that. But would POST requests be cached as well? I know there is no server side caching. The POST request is hitting an MVC page.

Comment: The post request will not be cached as long as no caching on the server